# Resetting json-server to the contents of db.json

Tags: json-server

NOTHING I do will get json-server to acknowledge changes to the db.json file. After reading https://github.com/typicode/json-server/issues/177. I have tried clearing the cache and closed all browser connections etc. (which is a pain enough in a workflow...) but still the data and schema persists in its last used state.

REST calls change the data, and the changes can be seen, that is working fine. But I need to change the schema...

How do I get json-server to restart using what is in the db.json file??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case it helps anyone else. I started json-server from the wrong folder, so it created and loaded a default db.json. I did not catch the warning

```
Oops, db.json doesn't seem to exist
Creating db.json with some default data
```

on the very first startup. So I was altering the "wrong" file!!! Just a note in case anyone else gets caught out.

Answer (score 2):

Steps:

1. Navigate to the path where json server is installed (json-server-master folder).
2. Rename the `db.json` as `db.json_bkp`
3. Restart the json server from command prompt 
   `json-server --watch db.json`

The db will be reset to the default values.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the similar issue.

Please check the db.json file that json-server is accessing and change it accordingly.
In my case, I was changing a different file than the correct one.

Please check for db.json file in the directory where you first installed/run the json-server. Change it according to your requirement.

Restart json-server so that changes will effect.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the folder where your db.json file resides. then run the command json-server --watch db.json

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same issue. I visited the the db directory (where the `db.json` file is situated).

Run `json-server --watch db.json` at the command prompt, while you are at the db directory.